# Ads are loading, but not showing?

Tags: java, android, database, string, admob

My interstitial ads are successfully loading, but when I call `.show()` on them, they don't show up.

I have followed [these](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#adding_interstitial_ads_to_an_activity) directions, and the ads load successfully, but don't show when I call `mInterstitialAd.show();`:

**In onCreate():**

```
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("My ID");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            beginPlayingGame();
        }
    });
        requestNewInterstitial();
```

**`requestNewInterstitial()`:**

```
  private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("Phone's ID")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM:**

```
 public void tryAgain(View v) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

            mInterstitialAd.show();
            Log.v(TAG, "LOADED in Game Over!");

        }
       else {
            beginPlayingGame();
        }

        beginPlayingGame();
    }
```

I get the log saying it is loaded in my log cat, but the ad doesn't actually show!  **Why is it loading, but not showing?**

P.S. I think I actually got it to work once earlier, but it stopped working ever since then. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I just had to remove the extra method call after the else. For example,

```
public void tryAgain(View v) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

            mInterstitialAd.show();
            Log.v(TAG, "LOADED in Game Over!");

        }
       else {
            beginPlayingGame();
        }

        beginPlayingGame();
    }
```

should have just been

```
public void tryAgain(View v) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

            mInterstitialAd.show();
            Log.v(TAG, "LOADED in Game Over!");

        }
       else {
            beginPlayingGame();
        }
    //NOTICE THERE Is NO EXTRA METHOD CALL OF **beginPlayingGame()**
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `.addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")` to your `AdRequestBuilder`

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
              .build();
```

Because in development step, if you made too many request on AdMob sometimes it starts to not showing ads. So on development process work with test ads. If it is work without any problem, when you publish your app on Play Store, your users also will see your ads without any problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually tried that, and it was working in the beginning, but it suddenly stopped working. Even with/without the ID...

Comment: Hmm than I don't see any reason to not working, but I suggest you to try to create another ad unit id and put it on your app and check results.

Comment: Yeah, this is really weird. I also tried with another ad unit id as well, but it is still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

// set the ad unit ID
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

loadInterstitialAds(mInterstitialAd);

 //Create loadInterstitialAds method
 public void loadInterstitialAds(final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("Phone's ID")
                .build();

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```